# How to find the median of n values Without using Arrays (or list or any other collection/ function that uses arrays/list)?

Tags: java, sorting, pseudocode, median

Scenario:

The user is supposed to enter N (the number of values)
followed by N values.

How can I output the median?

Comment: if the user inputs 'n' first, you can just ignore every input before n/2 or (n/2)+1

Comment: (pseudo tries showing your effort to solve the problem are welcome too...)

Comment: @LeventeSzabó only if the numbers are sorted

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: @LeventeSzabó Why is that? The inputs aren't sorted so, what if the supposed median is one of those n/2 or [ (n/2) + 1 ] values?

Comment: Sort the numbers and pick the middle one

Comment: @JackFlamp dont forget that if there is an even number of numbers then the median is the mean of the two middle ones

Comment: @fge  I've tried to find the max. and min. of the values and remove them and keep doing that until i reach to the final 1 or 2 values. But the problem is in remembering(storing) the other values. Like, i don't what value of n the user is going to input so i wouldn't know how many variables to create

Comment: @JackFlamp Is there a way to sort without using arrays? (like i said in the previous comment, i face difficulty in storing the values for further calculations)

Comment: This is really complicated, because without storing the data you can only iterate once, and I don't know of any algorithm that could sort in only one iteration, that's why I assumed that they are going to be sorted.

Comment: This is a weird task. The main method receives the values in an array. So you can't possibly avoid the array, I don't know how to solve it without an explicit storage.

Comment: There are other data structures than arrays that will hold your numbers, like a linked list or a tree. A binary search tree may be pretty well suited.

Comment: Without using arrays?  Sure!  Use a `List` (or any other `Collection`).

Comment: @AJNeufeld Nah, i'm pretty sure i'm not supposed to use that. :/

Comment: @Eonm how does the program receive the numbers? in a main method array or from a stream or a file or what?

Comment: C language version of the question (with answer): [Find mean,median without using arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090961/find-mean-median-without-using-arrays). It’s a good idea to search before posting a question.

Comment: If the numbers come in as a `stream`, then this is easy!  If N is even: `stream.sorted().skip(N/2-1).limit(2).average().getAsDouble()`.  (The N is odd case is even simpler)

Comment: @AJNeufeld, I would expect `Stream.sorted()` to use an array in its implementation. The asker will have to decide whether this disqualifies you solution.

Comment: I am not allowed to use beyond for, if and while loops (and basic operands).

Comment: Are classes, objects and references OK? Otherwise I fail to see how it can be done.

Comment: @OleV.V. They're okay

Answer (score 3):

Without `Array`, without `List`, or any other `Collection`.

```
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Number of numbers: ");
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Enter the %d numbers: ", N);
        double median = IntStream.range(0, N)
                .mapToDouble(i -> scanner.nextDouble())
                .sorted()
                .skip((N-1)/2)
                .limit(2-N%2)
                .average()
                .getAsDouble();
        System.out.printf("The median is %f%n", median);
    }
```

(Pay no attention to that man behind the `.sorted()` curtain.)

Comment: I’ll make sure to ignore that man. ;-)

Comment: I tested a bit, it works well for valid input. Very elegant solution.

Comment: what do you supply in range when you are using a stream from a list

Comment: @GilbertS It isn’t streaming from a list.  The range is being used to call `scanner.getDouble()` exactly `N` times.  There are other ways to do it, such as `stream.tokens().limit(N).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).sorted() ...` (untested), which would stop after taking the first N tokens from the scanner stream.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you hand program a binary tree. You probably need to allow duplicates, to Java’s built in `TreeSet` won’t do. It may also be that you can find a suitable tree implementation somewhere on the net. The tree should be sorted. See [*Binary search tree* on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) for more inspiration.

Your main program will read your numbers one by one and insert them into your tree. After that, it will query the tree for the middle element, or two middle elements if `N` is even.

You don’t need any array to implement your tree. For finding the ith element, the tree will perform an inorder traversal counting the elements encountered and returning the ith element.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need some storage for at least N/2 places. There's no way around that.

**EDITED after OP's coment:**

Get some good course on programming, esp. data structures. You can't rely on Stackoverflow for all your developer career ;-). Having said that, let's give you a starting point: I'd use an ArrayList here:

```
int n = ...; // get N from the user;
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    double element = ...; // get element from the user;
    list.add(element);
}
// Have the Java library sort the list for you
Collections.sort(list);
// now pick/compute the median from the sorted list
// I'll leave that up to you..
```

Comment: Yes this isn't as much a logical problem as much as a problem where to keep the values. I really don't understand it. But I want to solve it :)

Comment: That’s cheating. :-) An `ArrayList` of course uses an array behind the scenes.

Comment: Of course that's cheating. But there is no way to solve the problem without cheating one way or the other. Of course any sorted or sortable collection will do the job - ArrayList just comes in handy...